# Z-index Fabric.js objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, z-index, fabricjs

I would like to use fabricjs to create and manipulate shapes, but it's impossible to positionate them with z-index property in html page.

This is the control panel page that I would realize:

http://piramidart.it/Autosave/oaktree_html/index.html

Is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: Any ideas to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

use `canvas` methods:

```
canvas.bringToFront(object) 
canvas.bringForward(object)
canvas.sendToBack(object)
canvas.sendBackwards(object)
```